# Acronyms with same style as LOT? (acro package)

Tags: acronyms, acro

I've the very same question that was asked at 
[Acronyms with same style as LOT?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158870/acronyms-with-same-style-as-lot). However, I'm using the `acro` package, not the `acronym` package.

Any ideas?

Best regards, Alex

---

Update, it seems that the following mwe looks ok, however, it does not take the option "pages=first" into account:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareInstance{acro-page-number}{dotfill}{default}{ 
  punct = true , punct-symbol = \dotfill
} 
\acsetup{ 
 list-type    = table , 
 list-style   = longtable , 
 pages=first, page-name={}, pages-name={}, page-ref = dotfill
} 
\DeclareAcronym{foo}{ short = foo, long = {bar} } 
\begin{document} 
\ac{foo}\newpage \ac{foo}\newpage \ac{foo}\newpage
\printacronyms
\end{document}
```

Expected: `foo bar ........................................... 1`

Instead: `foo bar ........................................... pp.1–3`

---

Update: I noticed that this MWE always produces the warning `LaTeX Warning: Rerun to get page numbers of acronym bar in acronym list right`, no matter how often LaTeX has been executed.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareInstance{acro-page-number}{dotfill}{default}{ 
  punct = true , punct-symbol = \dotfill
} 
\acsetup{ 
 list-type    = table , 
 list-style   = longtable , 
 pages=first, page-name={}, pages-name={}, page-ref = dotfill
} 
\DeclareAcronym{bar}{ short = bar, long = {bar} } 
\DeclareAcronym{foo}{ short = foo, long = {foo} } 
\begin{document}
\printacronyms
\ac{foo}\newpage \ac{bar}\newpage \ac{foo}\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean with _LOT_?

Comment: Thanks. LOT = List of Tables. In general: All lists and the table of content have page numbers on the right with dots to fill the space. Only the list of acronyms looks different.

Comment: Review the [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/acro) The section 8 could be what you're looking for. Good luck.

Comment: With your example I don't get `pp.` but I *do* get the page range `1--3`. Unfortunately the option `pages=first` currently does nothing... this probably counts as a bug and should be corrected.

Comment: Right, I modified the example, since I figured out how to hide the "pp" already. Would highly appreciate if the pages=first option would be implemented or to know a workaround. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This'll be corrected in v1.6b. Maybe this weekend...

Comment: Nice. Have you noticed the second update in the question as well?

Comment: @clemens: do you have a workaround for the above mentioned MWE that always produces a warning? To reproduce: ```while true; do pdflatex mwe|grep warn; done```

Comment: @Alex this is fixed in my development version. Update to CTAN will follow soon

Comment: @clemens Thx! Will check it out then.

Answer (score 3):

With v2.1 or newer there is a list style `lof` and you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{acro}[2015/09/05]

\acsetup{ 
  list-style = lof ,
  pages = first
} 

\DeclareAcronym{bar}{ short = bar, long = {bar} } 
\DeclareAcronym{foo}{ short = foo, long = {foo} } 

\begin{document}

\printacronyms

\section{Blah blah}

\ac{foo}\newpage
\ac{bar}\newpage
\ac{foo}\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

With 1.6b (2015/05/10) your example works, inluding `pages=first` and without endless warnings.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{acro}

\DeclareInstance{acro-page-number}{dotfill}{default}{ 
  punct = true ,
  punct-symbol = \dotfill
} 

\acsetup{ 
  list-type = table , 
  list-style = longtable , 
  pages = first,
  page-name = ,
  pages-name = ,
  page-ref = dotfill
} 

\DeclareAcronym{bar}{ short = bar, long = {bar} } 

\DeclareAcronym{foo}{ short = foo, long = {foo} } 
\begin{document}

\printacronyms

\ac{foo}\newpage
\ac{bar}\newpage
\ac{foo}\newpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

A personal remark: while your initial question seems perfectly fine for TeX.sx both your first and you second update look more like bug reports to me. The `acro` website (mentioned also in the manual) https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/acro/ is much better suited for bug reports: a) I won't miss the report and b) I won't forget it. (Both happens with questions on TeX.sx quite easily...)

Comment: Very well, will use the bitbucket repo from now of, based on TeX Live 2015 with all the latest packages.

Comment: @Alex of course questions about how to do something with `acro` are well suited for this site – only bug reports and feature requests aren't :)